# Search in laravel-translatable attr like name of type (json) with laravel scout need to write the search word in case-sensitive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-scout, laravel-translatable

Using:

- spatie/laravel-translatable
- laravel/scout

The problem:
If i store translation for an attribute like description as json for example

```
description in table stored as
{"ar": "السلام عليكم", "en": "Welcome"}
```

If i write

```
Table::search("Welcome")->get(); 
// return the previous record.

Table::search("welcome")->get();
// no result come back.
```